# Duplicate icons, and some old ones in Dash

Tags: unity, icons

My issues is that I've some how managed to get duplicate icons (picture below) and some older icons. When I click on the duplicate / old icons it just takes me to the system settings. This is driving me mad, is there any way I can remove them without having to reinstall?

[image]

Comment: You must have old, outdated duplicate `.desktop` files in either `/usr/share/applications` or (more likely) in `~/.local/share/applications`. See the dupe above.

Comment: thank you !!! yes this is a duplicate of that post

Comment: @Joe Click the That solved my problem button so that future visitors get redirected! The [tour] and [help] should assist you in learning how to use the site.